# Filter to display articles from the last edition date only

Tags: 7, views

I have a magazine type project but articles are grouped into editions(issues). So I have 2 content-types interconnected using node reference.

What I need is to create a view to display only the articles of the last edition on frontpage. I can use a criteria of edition date or edition number (need the last one). Unfortunately I cannot find how to do do it. What value of the operator to enter.

[image]

Comment: Last edition means your last node on that 'type' ?

Comment: I have almost the same problem with a project, subscribing!

Answer (score 1):

What if you filter by **Edition Date**, order it by descending, and display only first value?

It should give you the last available edition, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

just enter the date as the value. If you are not sure about the format just add the "field_date" to show on the screen and copy and paste the date you want to filter by.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I need a generic variable (of last date) so when the new edition comes up I don't need to update the view filter too.

Comment: I assume this can be done using contextual filters?